# How to avoid "Ambiguous field in query" without adding Table Name or Table Alias in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-error-1064

I have a select query in which I have joined a couple of tables say `T1` and `T2` and both the tables have a field named STATUS which I don't need to fetch. In the where clause I need to add `WHERE STATUS=1` and some more conditions.

But somehow I just can't add the table name or table alias to the field in the where clause i.e. I can't use where `T2.STATUS=1`. Is there any way to always consider the `STATUS=1` from the where clause being `T1.STATUS` so that I can avoid "Ambiguous field error"?

Here is a sample query:

```
select T1.name, T1.address, T1.phone, T2.title, T2.description from T1
Left Join T2 on T1.CID=T2.ID
where STATUS = 1
```

In above query, I want the `STATUS =1` to always mean `T2.STATUS`

Comment: What's the problem with using alias? Let's try to fix it :)

Comment: I guess your simplified query does not contain the problem. Could you show the real query?

Comment: This query does contain the problem because it does not know whether it is STATUS in T1 or T2.

Comment: But you tried T1.Status and it did not work, right?

Comment: Actually this query is built in runtime in a php function. The Where clause is supplied as a parameter to the function and it can't be hard coded. There are many conditions in the where other than STATUS=1 or STATUS =0. I can't use the alias because I have called this function numerously throughout my project and instead of adding  alias to every function call, I thought it would be better to modify the actual function once only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you for some reason can't live with doing

```
select T1.name, T1.address, T1.phone, T2.title, T2.description from T1
Left Join T2 on T1.CID=T2.ID
where T2.STATUS = 1
```

Then I guess you could

```
SELECT T1.name, T1.address, T1.phone, T2.title, T2.description 
FROM (  SELECT CID, name, address, phone
        FROM T1) AS T1
LEFT JOIN T2
ON T1.CID=T2.ID
WHERE STATUS = 1
```

Basicly just skip getting the STATUS column from T1. Then there can be no conflict.

Bottomline; there's no simple way of doing this. The one closest to simple would be to have different names of both STATUS columns, but even that seems extreme.

Comment: Or try making of " T1.address, T1.phone, T2.title, T2.description 
FROM T1" a view and use it as if it's T1 :)

Comment: Problem with this is that the subquery is painfully slow if the outer query has lots of records.